# What is the difference between MVVM and MVI pattern in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, model-view-intent

What is the difference between MVVM and MVI pattern in Kotlin?

MVVM, and MVI are some of the common patterns in Android and they can broadly be thought of as different flavours of the same core concept — abstracting logic from the UI into classes without references to Android. Which architectural pattern is better for android development?